# How to change data attribute value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This might be a simple question but I have been experimenting for the last hour or so without a successful conclusion. Basically, I have the following HTML:

```
<div data-trackcolor="#f39e93" data-size="60" data-linewidth="3" data-animate="500" data-percent="0" data-linecap="butt" data-barcolor="#fff" class="easyPieChart" data-toggle="easypiechart" style="width: 60px; height: 60px; line-height: 60px;">
  <span class="white font-90">0%</span>
  <canvas height="65" width="65" style="width: 60px; height: 60px;"></canvas>
</div>
```

I'm trying to change the value of `data-trackcolor` element using the following jQuery syntax:

```
$('[data-toggle=easypiechart]').data('trackcolor','#f39e93');
```

I also tried `$(".easyPieChart").attr("data-trackcolor", "#f39e93");`.

The value is changing, the color is not changing. I'm suspecting this is because of the `canvas` element. In order to understand what this markup does, you can have a look at the following [URL](http://beyondadmin-v1.4.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/databoxes.html).

It displays the round circle in the colored databoxes. I would appreciate if someone might have some ideas why this is not working.

Thanks.

Comment: The color of what is not changing? and how is the color supposed to change by itself?

Comment: why would color change based on what you put in your `data-X` attribute?

Comment: attributes are not properties those changes. You might need to put some extra script to get this done.

Comment: @krafo did my answer helped you ?

Answer (score 5):

These data values are being used only once at the loading of page as per code written in [THIS](http://beyondadmin-v1.4.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/assets/js/charts/easypiechart/easypiechart-init.js) script file (from the link provided by you). So your changes made in these attributes dynamically won't affect the Charts colors or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

With `$.data` you can read and set data values but you can not write in the DOM with it.
From jQuery documentation of `data` method : https://api.jquery.com/data/

> ## Additional Notes:
>
> Note that this method currently does not provide cross-platform support for setting data on XML documents, as Internet Explorer does
>   not allow data to be attached via expando properties.

### Update

Don't mind this, I've confused the question.

<strike>As an alternative use the `attr` setter :</strike>

```js
$('#testBtn').on('click', function (ev){ 
 $("[data-toggle='easypiechart']").attr('data-trackcolor', '#f39e93');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-trackcolor="#fff" data-size="60" data-linewidth="3" data-animate="500" data-percent="0" data-linecap="butt" data-barcolor="#fff" class="easyPieChart" data-toggle="easypiechart" style="width: 60px; height: 60px; line-height: 60px;">
<span class="white font-90">0%</span>
<canvas height="65" width="65" style="width: 60px; height: 60px;"></canvas>
</div>

<button id="testBtn">Test</button>
```

After some further analyze I concluded : You don't need to change the data attribute because they are read only once at loading. To change the track color you need to get the `easyPieChart` instance and update it's options and trigger the `update` function.

The instance is assigned in the element data with the property name  `easyPieChart`.

See : http://beyondadmin-v1.4.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/assets/js/charts/easypiechart/jquery.easypiechart.js at line 167

```
   ...
   return c.data("easyPieChart", new a.easyPieChart(e, f))
   ...
```

#### Putting all together

```js
// simulates the initialisation
InitiateEasyPieChart.init();

// 
var getPies = function(){
 return $('[data-toggle="easypiechart"]');
};

var changePiesTrackColor = function(color){
  var $pies = getPies();
  $pies.each(function(idx, el){
    var $el = $(el);
    var easypiechartInstance = $el.data('easyPieChart');
    easypiechartInstance.options.trackColor = color;
    var currentValue  = $el.data('percent'); // there is no way to get the current Value from the instance because the scop of it is "privat".
    easypiechartInstance.update(currentValue);
    
  });
};
```

```html
<div data-trackcolor="#f39e93" data-size="60" data-linewidth="3" data-animate="500" data-percent="10" data-linecap="butt" data-barcolor="#fff" class="easyPieChart" data-toggle="easypiechart" style="width: 60px; height: 60px; line-height: 60px;">

</div>

<hr />
<button onclick="changePiesTrackColor(getcolor('#0000ff'))">blue</button>
<button onclick="changePiesTrackColor(getcolor('#00ff00'))">green</button>
<button onclick="changePiesTrackColor(getcolor('#ff0000'))">red</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://beyondadmin-v1.4.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/assets/js/beyond.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://beyondadmin-v1.4.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/assets/js/charts/easypiechart/jquery.easypiechart.js"></script>
<script src="http://beyondadmin-v1.4.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/assets/js/charts/easypiechart/easypiechart-init.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Puneet,

I was actually calling the script on page load, in order to solve the issue i put the call to the script in the function which changes the colors like the following:-

```
function changeWidgetColor()
{
    var percentageValue = $(".easyPieChart").attr('data-percent');

    if (percentageValue <= 20)
    {
        $(".easyPieChart").attr("data-trackcolor", "#f39e93");

        InitiateEasyPieChart.init();
    }
```

}

Comment: Np @krafo. Please accept my answer if it helped you :)